# Where to buy a domain for my local server

Tags: web-hosting, domains, domain-registration, localhost

I have made a website and hosted in my local computer using a static ip

Where can i buy a domain name such as `www.something.com` such that it can redirect to my static IP.

So that if i m using a page like a `http://localhost/index.jsp` it can be accessed by `http://www.something.com/index.jsp`

Does it matter if i run the server locally or should I buy a managed web hosting server from a big company if the traffic is low on my site?

Answer (score 3):

If you host it locally you will need to set up DNS for your domain name and it will need to be able to handle dynamic IP addresses if you do not have a static IP address. If you have a static IP address at home then you can use a company like ZoneEdit to manage your DNS for you and point your domain to your home IP. If you have dynamic IP address then you can [DynDNS.com](http://www.dyndns.com/) to handle your DNSas they offer software that manages the changing IP address for you and allows users to always find you using your domain name.

If you get hosting from a hosting provider you don't have to worry about any of that.

Otherwise the hosting will be similar although if you host it yourself you obviously can do whatever you want with your webserver and don't have to worry about restrictions placed on you by your host.

Comment: can i use a domain(.com) with dyndns like currently using pradyut.dyndns.org, can i www.something.com redirect to pradyut.dyndns.org without redirecting (hiding pradyut.dyndns.org)

Comment: Yes but I am unsure exactly how it is done. I am pretty sure you'll need to use both ZoneEdit and dyndns.com to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Buy `yourdomain.com` from a domain reseller. Make sure they allow you to setup the DNS of the domain from their control panel. Many resellers offer the DNS with the domain and allow you to change it using a simple control panel.
2. After you bought the domain, enter the control panel for the DNS and set up these records:

   yourdomain.com      | A | your.static.IP
   www.yourdomain.com  | A | your.static.IP
   mail.yourdomain.com | A | your.static.IP (this last record only if you set up also a mail server on your computer)

Obviously replace `your.static.IP` with the real static IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX of your home computer.

Then you are all set up. Now you need only to keep your computer running, otherwise people won't be able to see your site.

Anyway for a production site I highly discourage this approach, and considering the cheap price of webhosting I would rather buy a Linux webhosting plan with cPanel on it (i.e http://www.qualityhostonline.com) and place your website there. It's also an opportunity for you to learn cPanel, while setting up the website on your PC you would learn useless stuff because nobody will ever want a site to be hosted there for real.

Comment: actually i have to host on glassfish (for ejbs) and for that the price is not less than $30/mo. and also i make changes on a daily basis...so uploading(database and applcation) would also be a issue...so thats why a local computer is good for me...

Comment: @Pradyut Bhattacharya, you're paying too much for your host.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Most of the GlassFish web hosting plans I've seen are VPS. So that's not too much. That said, there are some $20/month VPS plans out there, and there are even some shared hosting plans that support GlassFish: http://blogs.sun.com/arungupta/entry/totd_153_glassfish_hosting_options

Answer (score 0):

we can also do this using a free name server and we can update the nameserver automatically of our dynamic ip

http://freedns.afraid.org/